# Strange scrolling phenomenon using ratchet on iOS

Tags: scroll, ratchet-2

[image]

Recently I was troubled by the strange scrolling phenomenon on IOS using ratchet. Like the picture above demonstrate, most of time scrolling works fine. But sometimes, a black block appears from bottom and going up to swallow the web content with fingers scrolling up.

Is there anyone who encountered the similar issue with me? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this happens when you are coming outside the app like the notification bar, etc. Instead of showing a blank space it is showing a black space covering some of the content, **try to tap inside the app before scrolling.**

Comment: @clintgh, I double checked that this phenomenon will occur even though my finger is tapped inside the app at the beginning of scrolling.